# Create a log in system in pygame python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Trying to get the following python code working. What I am trying to do is, for the password input box, instead of the characters inputted appearing, I want asterisks to appear.

I have tried using other variables and displaying them, but it hasn't worked. I have been able to get the correct number of asterisks stored in a variable, but need help with over-writing the text in the password box with the asterisks.

The code is:

```
import pygame, pygame.font, pygame.event, pygame.draw, string
from pygame.locals import *
import hashlib, uuid

string=''
hashed_password=''
current_string_p=[]
display_p=[]
symbol='*'

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)

  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
  pygame.font.init()
  current_string_un = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string_un))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string_un = current_string_un[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_LSHIFT or inkey == K_RSHIFT:
      inkey=get_key()
      if inkey <= 127:
        upper_case=inkey-32
        current_string_un.append(chr(upper_case))
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string_un.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string_un))
  return string.join(current_string_un)
#password
  global display_p
  global current_string_p
  current_string_p = []
  display_p=[]
  pro=''.join(display_p)
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + pro)
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string_p = current_string_p[0:-1]
      display_p = display_p[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
##      print(display_p))
      break
    elif inkey == K_LSHIFT or inkey == K_RSHIFT:
      inkey=get_key()
      if inkey <= 127:
        upper_case=inkey-32
        for character in current_string_p:
          display_p.append(symbol)
        pro=''.join(display_p)
        display_box.blit(screen, question + ": " + pro)
        current_string_p.append(chr(upper_case))
    elif inkey <= 127:
      for character in current_string_p:
        display_p.append(symbol)
      pro=''.join(display_p)
      display_box.blit(screen, question + ": " + pro)
      current_string_p.append(chr(inkey))


##  return string.join(display_p)
  return display_p
##  return string.join(current_string_p)

def strong_password(password):
    #a strong password will have a capital letter, a lowercase letter and a number
    passloop = 1
    hasdigit = 0
    uppercase = 0
    #checks each character to check password meets requirements
    for character in password:
        if character.isdigit():
            hasdigit += 1
        else:
            pass
        if character == character.upper():
            if character.isdigit():
                pass
            else:
                uppercase += 1
        else:
            pass
    if hasdigit > 0 and uppercase > 0:
        passloop = 2
        print('strong password')
    else:
        passloop = 1
        print('weak password')

def main():
  global display_p
  display_p=[]
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
  print (ask(screen, "Username") + " was entered")
  x = ask(screen, "Password")
  for character in x:
    display_p.append(symbol)
  pro=''.join(display_p)
  print (x + " was entered")
  print(pro)
  #check password security
  strong_password(x)
  #hash password
  salt = "5gz"
  hashing_password = x+salt
  h = hashlib.md5(hashing_password.encode())
  print(h.hexdigest())

if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

I think the issue is with this section:

```
#password
  global display_p
  global current_string_p
  current_string_p = []
  display_p=[]
  pro=''.join(display_p)
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + pro)
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string_p = current_string_p[0:-1]
      display_p = display_p[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
##      print(display_p))
      break
    elif inkey == K_LSHIFT or inkey == K_RSHIFT:
      inkey=get_key()
      if inkey <= 127:
        upper_case=inkey-32
        for character in current_string_p:
          display_p.append(symbol)
        pro=''.join(display_p)
        display_box.blit(screen, question + ": " + pro)
        current_string_p.append(chr(upper_case))
    elif inkey <= 127:
      for character in current_string_p:
        display_p.append(symbol)
      pro=''.join(display_p)
      display_box.blit(screen, question + ": " + pro)
      current_string_p.append(chr(inkey))


##  return string.join(display_p)
  return display_p
##  return string.join(current_string_p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just render `'*'` times the length of your password.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 42)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    password = ''

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    # Do something with the password and reset it.
                    print(password)  # I just print it to see if it works.
                    password = ''
                else:  # Add the character to the password string.
                    password += event.unicode

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # Render the asterisks and blit them.
        password_surface = FONT.render('*'*len(password), True, (70, 200, 150))
        screen.blit(password_surface, (30, 30))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```